# How to use 'flatten' correctly in Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Our pipeline looks like this:

**GCS (gz compressed files) -> ParDo -> BigQuery**

I want to use a 'flatten' to scoop in multiple files from GCS as the input to my pipeline. But it keeps borking with the error:

```
Workflow failed. Causes: (5001e5764f46ac2c): BigQuery creation of import job for table "Impressions_05_2015_denormalized_test" in dataset "CPT_XXXX" in project "gdfp-XXXX" failed. Causes: (5001e5764f46a1cf): Error:
 Message: Load configuration must specify at least one source URI
 HTTP Code: 400
```

Code:

```
PCollection<String> file1 = pipeline.apply(TextIO.Read.from("gs://<bucket_name_removed>/NetworkActiveViews_232503_20140918_21.gz").withCompressionType(TextIO.CompressionType.GZIP));
        PCollection<String> file2 = pipeline.apply(TextIO.Read.from("gs://<bucket_name_removed>/NetworkActiveViews_232503_20140918_22.gz").withCompressionType(TextIO.CompressionType.GZIP));
        PCollectionList<String> allFiles = PCollectionList.of(file1).and(file2);
        PCollection<String> inputRead = allFiles.apply(Flatten.<String>pCollections());
inputRead.apply(ParDo.of(transformation)
                .named(String.format("%s-CPT-transform", type))
                .withSideInputs(views))
                .apply(Write.to(getOutputTable(type))
                        .withCreateDisposition(CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
                        .withWriteDisposition(WRITE_APPEND)
                        .withSchema(schema)
                        .named(String.format("%s-BQ-write", type)));
```

Example job id: **2015-05-12_19_54_06-10158770219525037626**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The flatten looks fine.  The "import job" of the error message is used to sink data to BQ.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure the flatten code is OK. Looks like a bug in the BigQuery write step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the hack proposed, which is really quite gnarly, I instead write a single empty row in the `finishBundle()` method. This will write 1 empty row per bundle, but we can live with that until the fix is rolled out. Setting the "id" makes it much easier to filter those rows out later on.

Also, this workaround/hack is much easier to implement:

```
@Override
public void finishBundle(Context c) throws Exception {
   TableRow workaroundRow = new TableRow();
   workaroundRow.set("id", "workaround_row");
   c.output(workaroundRow); //Workaround to http://goo.gl/CpBxEf
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug on our end when writing an empty PCollection to BigQuery. I've got a repro of the issue -- we'll get it fixed asap and follow up here.

If you need to be able to create a result PCollection that might be empty, and you can handle a single empty row being added to the BigQuery table in the case of an empty result, you can temporarily work around the issue for now using this hack:

```
// Temporary hack around a temporary bug writing empty PCollections to BigQuery by
// creating a single empty row if a PCollection<TableRow> is empty.
static class AddEmptyRowIfEmpty
        extends PTransform<PCollection<TableRow>, PCollection<TableRow>> {

    @Override
    public PCollection<TableRow> apply(PCollection<TableRow> maybeEmpty) {

        // Build a PCollection that contains no elements if 'maybeEmpty' has elements, or
        // exactly one empty TableRow if 'maybeEmpty' is empty.
        final PCollectionView<Iterable<TableRow>> maybeEmptyView = maybeEmpty.apply(
                View.<TableRow>asIterable());
        PCollection<TableRow> singleRowIfMaybeEmptyIsEmpty =
                maybeEmpty.getPipeline()
                    .apply(Create.of((Void) null)).setCoder(VoidCoder.of())
                    .apply(ParDo.of(
                        new DoFn<Void, TableRow>() {
                          @Override
                          public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
                            Iterator<TableRow> rows = c.sideInput(maybeEmptyView).iterator();
                            if (!rows.hasNext()) {
                              c.output(new TableRow());
                            }
                          }
                        }).withSideInputs(maybeEmptyView));

        // Return a PCollection with at least one element.
        return PCollectionList.of(singleRowIfMaybeEmptyIsEmpty).and(maybeEmpty)
                .apply(Flatten.<TableRow>pCollections());

    }
}

// Then in your pipeline:
...
.apply(new AddEmptyRowIfEmpty())
.apply(BigQueryIO.Write(...))
```

Comment: Have you got a rough idea when the fix will be rolled out?

Comment: Have you got a rough idea when the fix will be rolled out?