# Handling empty PCollections with BigQuery in Apache Beam

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Using the following code, I am getting the following errors when trying to write to BigQuery

I am using Apache-Beam 2.0.0

`Exception in thread "main" org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline$PipelineExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException`

If I change the `text.startsWith` to `D`, everything works fine (i.e. so something is output).

*Is there someway to catch or watch for empty PCollections?*

Based on the StackTrace it looks like the error is actually in BigQueryIO - the file left in my bucket has 0 bytes and maybe this is causing BigQueryIO a problem.

My use case is that I am using side outputs for DeadLetters and encountered this error when my job produced no dead-letter output, so robustly handling this would be useful.

The job should really be able to run in batch or streaming mode, my best guess is to write any output to GCS / TextIO in batch mode and GBQ when streaming, if that sounds sensible?

Any help gratefully received.

```
public class EmptyPCollection {

public static void main(String [] args) {

    PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();
    options.setTempLocation("gs://<your-bucket-here>/temp");
    Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);
    String schema = "{\"fields\": [{\"name\": \"pet\", \"type\": \"string\", \"mode\": \"required\"}]}";
    String table = "<your-dataset>.<your-table>";
    List<String> pets = Arrays.asList("Dog", "Cat", "Goldfish");
    PCollection<String> inputText = pipeline.apply(Create.of(pets)).setCoder(StringUtf8Coder.of());
    PCollection<TableRow> rows = inputText.apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, TableRow>() {
        @ProcessElement
        public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
            String text = c.element();
            if (text.startsWith("X")) {  // change to (D)og and works fine
                TableRow row = new TableRow();
                row.set("pet", text);
                c.output(row);
            }
        }
    }));

    rows.apply(BigQueryIO.writeTableRows().to(table).withJsonSchema(schema)
            .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
            .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED));

    pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish();

}
```

}

```
[direct-runner-worker] INFO org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.TableRowWriter - Opening TableRowWriter to gs://<your-bucket>/temp/BigQueryWriteTemp/05c7a7c0786a4656abad97f11ef23d8e/2675e1c7-f4d7-4f78-a85f-a38095b57e6b.

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline$PipelineExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner$DirectPipelineResult.waitUntilFinish(DirectRunner.java:322)
at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner$DirectPipelineResult.waitUntilFinish(DirectRunner.java:292)
at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner.run(DirectRunner.java:200)
at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner.run(DirectRunner.java:63)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:295)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:281)
at EmptyPCollection.main(EmptyPCollection.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteTables.processElement(WriteTables.java:97)
```

Comment: Looks the same bug I hit a while back: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30204862/how-to-use-flatten-correctly-in-dataflow. Might be worthwhile raising it here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:187168%20status:open

Comment: Sure does look like the same thing. Thank you very much - at least it's not me going mad! Will look into raising an issue and getting this a bit more attention, sort of thing that might trip jobs up in the long run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the BigQuery sink implementation within Apache Beam. Filing a bug in the Apache Beam Jira would be the appropriate place to file this.

I have filed https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-2406 to track this issue.